# Disable charging of connected USB device (phone)

Tags: linux, usb, android, thinkpad, charging

I often use my phone as a mobile internet hotspot, which is connected via USB to my computer. This works fine, but unless the phone is already fully charged, it starts charging its battery from the notebook, draining the battery of the latter quite quickly. Since it is a USB-C port on both ends, I suspect that the charging current may even exceed 0.5A, leading to a fairly quick discharge of my notebook's battery. I would prefer to completely disable charging of the phone when my notebook itself runs on battery power. A current limit to the USB's minimum 0.1A would also be ok. Entirely disabling the port is not an option, as that would also disable USB tethering.

Question: How can I disable USB charging of a connected device or at least limit the current to 0.1A?

Notebook: Lenovo Thinkpad T480
OS: Ubuntu 20.04
Phone: SHIFT phone, running Android 8, not rooted

Thank you and best regards,
Philipp

Comment: Short answer: Not possible. Suggestion: Use WiFi AP instead.

Comment: … which however uses more power.

Comment: Disabling charging is possible with root permissions on a lot of devices. Some manufacturers also add an option to limit battery charging to a certain level, e.g. some Lenovo devices can be limited to start charging below 40% and stop charging above 60%.

Comment: @ChanganAuto: The WIFI AP is not really better, as it will drain the battery faster on both devices. And I don't like to have my AP on all the time when travelling...

Comment: @Robert: I might follow the path of rooting the phone, although a less invasive option would be preferred.

Comment: Never tried it but search for "USB data only cable" - as data and power are transmitted via different wires there are plenty ways to disable the power connection physically but keeping the data connection.

Comment: @Robert: Good point, I haven't thought of that. Very hacky, but also very definite. Since it would be a clear violation of the specs, the data connection might fail, but it could be worth a try. Thanks.

Comment: Hi! Have you been able to find a solution? BTW, you mentioned specs, have you read that laptops should charge phones, not vice versa?

Comment: I've tried (for type A - type C cable) to cover voltage (+) with tape -> the phone stopped to be recognized by Thinkpad / Linux laptop. I think for USC-C to USB-C similar method would also result in no connection.

Comment: @Martian2020 Of course the notebook should charge the phone and this is what it does. But I wanted to disable charging both ways. Unfortunately, I have not yet found a solution. I skimmed through the Linux kernel source code of the USB enumeration stuff, but there seems to be no way to tamper with the power budget or configuration selection.

Comment: Philip, hi again. I'm also on Linux and Android. I used wi-fi tethering and IIRC it worked fine; recently tried USB tethering and internet quickly stops working with USB. Why don't you use wi-fi? Does your mobile internet work with USB better? Thank you!

Comment: @Martian2020 USB tethering works fine for me, except for the charging thing. WiFi tethering works as well, but especially when in a train, I prefer not to pollute the RF spectrum even more; plus the cable does not open up another connection for attacks.

Comment: @PhilippBurch Do you *think*, or do you *know* that the phone continues to charge (consume excessive power from USB) even when its "100%" charged?

Comment: @U.Windl: The phone becomes cooler after reaching 100%, so although I haven't measured it, I very strongly assume that it stops drawing much power when the battery is full. I also indicated this in the question: "... unless the phone is already fully charged, it starts charging its battery from the notebook ..."

Answer (score 2):

That is not possible. The function of USB charging is built into the motherboard. You would have to find a way to disable USB charging on the phone's end, but that may require rooting. A viable solution right now would be to use a wireless method to connect to your phone instead.

Comment: "not possible" seems a bit hard. If the phone complies with the USB spec, it must limit its input current depending on what the hub advertises as being available (or, alternatively, fail to connect if the available current is too low). Maybe it would be somehow possible to change what the hub says, but I don't know how.

Comment: Yes, the device also announces the power it consumes; if the host would limit the "current drawable" to the devices claim, an intelligent adapter between host and phone could limit the current the phone could draw, I guess. However I never heard of such a thing.

Answer (score 1):

#### Host side

I’ve looked over at the [electrical engineering stackexchange](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/448198/complexity-of-a-b-for-ordinal-notations), and apparently, **that’s not something software at the host side can control,** as usually the chip itself (that does the data communication) is kept in a reset state unless power is connected first, and even if you can disable negotiating of higher charging rates, 0.5A or 0.1A will always be delivered as defined by the spec. **It’s the gadget device that decides** how much of that minimum it will use. At best you could put an old hub in-between that can only deliver 0.1A per port.

#### Gadget side

On the gadget side, it’s quite easy, and there are **apps for it, like “Battery Charge Limit” (e.g. over at XDA)**. But “thanks” to Google, those apps **need root**. (There *are* locked-down phones that have something like that build-in. But I haven’t yet seen one myself.)

#### Alternatives

**A less in-the-box solution is to enable your phone’s wifi hotspot or bluetooth connection sharing, and just use that.**

The big limitation there is that (on Android,) ADB doesn’t let you create a debug connection over wifi unless you previously enabled it via USB. Every time. Which is said to be for security “reasons”. But really it’s just laziness or incompetence, as it can very much be made secure, just like SSH for example, which literally runs on Google’s own servers.

I’ve made a small udev script with a GUI helper before, that automated it as much as is possible: You connect the phone via USB, it tells you it’s “hot”, you disconnect the cable again, and then it sets up the connection via wifi hotspot. Without root, you still have to manually enable the hotspot though. So it’s not much of a help, and I’ve abandoned it unless I’m debugging.

#### Moral of the story

NEVER. EVER. buy any device that you do not control.
Because otherwise this would be trivial to control in your phone’s custom configuration.

Comment: That's not a link to electrical engineering stackexchange.

Comment: As mentioned, that link doesn't go to ee stackexchange. It goes to mathoverflow.net.  Also would you be willing to share your code?